# Pylint error: concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly

Tags: pylint

When running `pylint -j 8 *` I get following error:

> concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process
> pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
>
> Exception in thread QueueManagerThread: Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in
> _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 394, in
> _queue_management_worker
> work_item.future.set_exception(bpe)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 547, in
> set_exception
> raise InvalidStateError('{}: {!r}'.format(self._state, self)) concurrent.futures._base.InvalidStateError: CANCELLED: <Future at
> 0x7fa3786b6ee0 state=cancelled>

Same error occurs with `pylint -j 2 *`.

It used to work fine. This started happening suddenly today.  I dont remember updating any thing on Ubuntu

`sudo dmesg` gives me

```
Out of memory: Killed process 9418 (pylint) total-vm:10583184kB, 
anon-rss:9122024kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 
pgtables:20176kB oom_score_adj:0
```